# mean[:, None, None] crashes in Pytorch / jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch

I previously had this "data_transforms" that I was using to construct my dataloader :

```py
data_transforms_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor()
])
```

Everything was working fine and I could train my model without any problem.
I decided to include a normalization step at the end of the transformations:

```py
data_transforms_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((512, 512)),
    transforms.RandomVerticalFlip(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.8979], std=[0.3025])
])
```

Adding this started caused my notebook to crash. In other words, I didn't get any python message error but the notebook kernel kernel kept crashing and restarting.
At first I thought it was a memory error so I changed my batch_size to 1 to verify but it wasn't the problem.

I tried to inspect so I applied the transformations one by one and copied the "to_normalize" source code from https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torchvision/transforms/functional.html

```py
training_set = Dataset(partition['train'], labels, transform=None)
d = transforms.functional.resize(training_set.__getitem__(3)[0], (512,512))
x = transforms.functional.to_tensor(d)
# Normalization code
mean, std = [0.7], [0.3025]
mean, std = torch.as_tensor(mean, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device), torch.as_tensor(std, dtype=x.dtype, device=x.device)
```

So far so good. When I add this :

```py
tensor.sub_(mean[:, None, None]).div_(std[:, None, None])
```

The notebook crashes again (no python error, just the kernel crashing and restarting). When I isolated the parts, it turned out that mean[:, None, None] (or/also std[:, None, None]) causes the notebook to crash.

Does anyone have any idea why is that happening ?

Comment: What do you mean by crash? Are you getting a Python stack trace or javascript errors of the notebook itself, or what? In any case, you should post that in a digestible form.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your tensor is some kind of integer. In that case *mean* and *std* are converted to integers (=0) in Normalize, which causes a zero-division. Try making sure that the tensor, you are normalizing, is a float.